# The font is different/wrong for personal statements on Careers

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, cv, design

The font matches the preview window, yet when you save the content the font is different and smaller than the rest of the CV. The font for everything else however appears to be "correct".

Is there a way to format this with Markdown or is this something that has not been noticed?

**Edit**

Please see: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/shaun-finglas

By "save" the content I mean exactly that. Edit your CV, view the preview window and the font will match the rest of the CV. However upon saving the font is different.

Comment: I should add, there is a quote mark, yet no closing one. Is this doing some formatting behind the scenes when we save a CV? By quote mark I mean the image in the upper left part of the personal statement.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with regards to "When you save the content"?

Comment: Or can you take and post screen shots of what you are experiencing?

Comment: @NickLarsen I think what's being reported is the fact that the rendered view personal statement has the class `quoted` applied to it (which renders the text with Georgia/serif fonts, different from the other text blocks on the page), whereas the edit preview for the same area doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the preview container to have the same classes as the content container, so the preview should be more accurate from now on.  Thanks for the feedback and everyone who helped clarify the problem.